# ffmpeg.exe ignores yadif filter when using >1 filter on the command line

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using Windows and batch converting some SD captures that are 544x576, I want to deinterlace them and scale them to show at the proper aspect ratio. When I use the following command:

`FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s/b *.576p.mkv') DO c:\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~fG" -y -filter:v yadif -filter:v scale=in_w:in_h,setsar=1.4118/1 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -level 3.1 -preset slow -c:a copy "%%~dpnG.out.mkv"`

The resultant file is still clearly interlaced, but the video specs show as progressive. Any ideas what would cause this? I'm having to do it in two stages using:

`FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s/b *.576p.mkv') DO c:\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~fG" -y -filter:v yadif  -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -level 3.1 -preset slow -c:a copy "%%~dpnG.di.mkv"`

then

`FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s/b *.576p.di.mkv') DO c:\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~fG" -y -filter:v scale=in_w:in_h,setsar=1.4118/1 -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -level 3.1 -preset slow -c:a copy "%%~dpnG.x264.mkv"`

..which is sub-optimal as it would do two separate encodes. However the .di.mkv file is not interlaced (looking at the video with left to right motion there's no combing present)

What would cause the first (yadif) filter to be ignored?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use one [filtergraph](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1) and join [simple filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Simple-filtergraphs) with a comma:

```
-filter:v "filter1,filter2,filter3"
```

Your scale isn't doing anything. For example, a 320x240 input with `scale=in_w:in_h` is the same as `scale=320:240`.